# VBA set range to a cell in a table (error object variable not set)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called DB.
On that sheet I have a table called Details.
In the table there is column called AccountID.

Now I want to set a range to be the first cell on that column.

I am trying:

```
Dim importRange As Range
Set importRange = DB.ListObjects("Details").ListColumns("AccountID").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)
```

I get the following error:
Object variable or with block variable not set

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like something hasn't been set properly. But it's outside of that snippet of code. Is `DB` set? The part you show should work.

Comment: DB exists, the name of the table and column are correct. Also tried to save only this part in a separate file, still get the same error

Comment: Well It works fine for me. Show the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your worksheet is called DB, try the following...

```
Dim importRange As Range
Set importRange = Worksheets("DB").ListObjects("Details").ListColumns("AccountID").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)
```

If DB is a variable, you'll need to assign it your worksheet.  So, for example, if your worksheet is called Sheet1, try...

```
Dim DB As Worksheet
Set DB = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim importRange As Range
Set importRange = DB.ListObjects("Details").ListColumns("AccountID").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something's not right. You could try this to figure out what.

```
Dim lo As ListObjects
Dim lc As ListColumns
Dim dbr As Range
Dim importRange As Range

Set lo = DB.ListObjects("Details")
Set lc = lo.ListColumns("AccountID")
Set dbr = lc.DataBodyRange
Set importRange = dbr.Cells(1, 1)
```

Step through the code with the debugger and check the values of the variable on each line.